# How to match close-by coordinates of two layers in a "Join by location"?

Tags: qgis-3, pyqgis-3

I have two (point) layers with similar but not equal coordinates (e.g. 4.54323**24** and 4.54323**82**) that represent data covering the same area (e.g. 1 km²).

The attributes of very close-by points shall be matched. The layers have many million points each so that buffer operations and *Join attributes by nearest* will be very costy.

I have read of a workaround where to save a file to CSV (coordinate values are truncated during export) and read in again in order to loose coordinate precision. Are there any "usual" geometric functions that truncate or round geometric coordinates of features or vertices in a determined way (i.e. precision) without the need to export and re-import? Any other ideas how to tackle the issue?

Comment: Try [Snap points to grid](https://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vector_general_tools/snappointstogrid.html) first

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use `join attributes by nearest` instead of `location`, since points seldomly match completely.

It works similarly to `join by location`, but instead of the intersection-type you define how many neighbours you want to join (in your case one) and how large the distance to the next neighbour should be in the worst case (e.g. 10 m).

Another solution would be to buffer one layer by e.g. 10 m and then join the buffered layer to the other.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The two options 'join by location' and using a buffer layer were also my first ideas. As I need to treat with big (point) data worldwide I was looking for a _less costy_ method. Any more options?